# why i am getting unhandled error event in event.js while running node js program

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-modules, node-webkit

I am new to node js. I have created a server.js in visual studio code editor and two html file under view folder and one main.js file for rendering that html code.
While i debug the server.js file then I am getting unhandle error event in event.js at line 160. Why i am getting this error.

```
var express    =    require('express');
var app        =    express();

require('./router/main')(app);
app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/css'));
console.log("__dirname : "+__dirname);
var server     =    app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("Express is running on port 3000");
});
```

[See Error Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdLwT.png)

Comment: your 3000 port is in use try changing port or releasing it

Comment: Thanks @harse zalavadiya.

Comment: I have one more question

Comment: i used css file i my html page using app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/css')); but it not works for me.

Comment: maybe you are not mapping it properly please use it like app.use('/css', express.static('css'))

Comment: yeah. Its working now.